# BeautifulSoup: finding elements within elements

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to find a list of games from the below website under the "a" category. I can find the `div` with an `id` attribute of value "letter-a" but not the `li` elements directly within no matter what pattern I try.

```
import bs4
import logging
import requests

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s - \
%(levelname)s - %(message)s")

##res = requests.get("http://www.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-one/backward-\
##compatibility")
res = requests.get("http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/backward-\
compatibility/available-games")
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
#game_elems = soup.select("body[id=\"DocumentBody\"] div[id=\"bodycolumn\"]")
game_elems = soup.select("#letter-a li")

logging.info("Length added elements: {}".format(len(game_elems)))
if game_elems:
    logging.info("First element in 'game_elems': {}".format(str(game_elems[0])))
```

[image]

Comment: What patterns have you tried? What does the html look like that you are trying to target?

Comment: Lots :) Added an img of html.

Comment: You forgot to describe what's not working in details, what are the outputs you're getting and what are the outputs you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can scrape a DOM modified by JS by controlling a browser with Selenium. To do it with Selenium, you could do it like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/backward-compatibility/available-games")

elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#letter-a")
print elem.get_attribute('innerHTML')
driver.close()
```

You can also control other browsers with Selenium, including headless browsers (browsers that run in the background, without opening a window) like PhantomJS.

---

Previously I had noticed that the HTML is malformed – You shouldn't have a `div` directly inside the `ul`. But that wasn't the blocking problem in the end.

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate how to use other parser's.

Comment: I added some examples in my answer.

Comment: Much appreciated Ivan! Thanks alot.

Comment: Hmm. I'm having issues installing lxml, which I'm in process of resolving, but the html5lib parser does not find my li elements either. What's more in the example you gave, html.parser finds the li element containing "aaa":/